# Is it possible to find elements that do not follow the locator?

Tags: protractor

**Current situation that is repeated several times:**

```
<div ng-repeat="r in ids">
  <span> DESIRED TEXT </span>
  <div ng-repeat="c in ids">
    <span> ng-bind-html="" UNDESIRED TEXT</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried using: `element.all(by.repeater('r in ids')).all(by.tagName('span')).getText()`

The problem is that this includes the second span as well. I would greatly prefer not to use xpath in the answer. So is there a way to specify only the first of each `<span>`, or to filter by not having `ng-bind-html`, etc?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found a solution:**

```
element.all(by.repeater('r in ids')).each(function (theElement, index) {
  theElement.all(by.tagName('span')).first().getText().then(function (text){
    console.log(text);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use css selector to find the same:

element.all(by.css("div[ng-repeat='r in ids'] span")).getText();

Hope this helps.